# Worksheet Change on Data Range / Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and perusing YouTube and StackOverflow to figure somethings out.

[image]

What I have here is a table for Hours and Overtime % by week.  Overtime % is determined by the formula OT% = MAX(0,(Hours*1.05-35)/Hours)*

I want users of my model to be able to change Hours OR OT, and the the other value to recalculate.  I can do with for the first row with the following

Sheet1 Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$J$2" Or Target.Address = "$K$2" Then
        Call cellUpdate(Target.Address)
    End If
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub cellUpdate(Target As String)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If Target = "$J$2" Then
            .Range("$K$2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, .Range("$J$2").Value * .Range("$G$2").Value + .Range("$G$3").Value) / .Range("$J$2").Value
        ElseIf Target = "$K$2" Then
            .Range("$J$2").Value = -.Range("$G$3").Value / (.Range("$G$2").Value - .Range("$K$2").Value)
        End If
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works great.  If I change J2, K2 updates.  If I change K2, J2 updates.

My questions:

- How can I make this work for all rows in the table?
- Do I have to define the cells by Row # and Column Letter, or can I define by table name and row header?
- What if the end user pastes a value in both J and K by mistake?
- What if the end user pastes over multiple rows in J or K, updating multiple weeks simultaneously?
- Can I change the references to M and B to something named, perhaps in a hidden sheet?

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

*this exact formula is made up, but for groups of employees (Hrs-40)/Hrs is not accurate since not everyone works 40 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is probably not the best solution but it is what I have managed to learn.

Worksheet Code:

```
Dim UpdateOT As Boolean
Dim oldarr As Variant
Dim newarr As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim therow As Long
    Dim thecol As Long

    therow = Target.Row
    thecol = Target.Column

    newarr = Target
    
    If UpdateOT = True And Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Hours").Range.Column = Target.Column Then
        Call OTUpdate(newarr, therow, thecol)
    ElseIf UpdateOT = True And Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("OT%").Range.Column = Target.Column Then
        Call HoursUpdate(newarr, therow, thecol)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim colcount As Long
    
    UpdateOT = False
    oldarr = Target
    colcount = Target.Columns.Count
    
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And (Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Hours").Range.Column = Target.Column Or Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("OT%").Range.Column = Target.Column) And Target.Row > Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.Row Then
        UpdateOT = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Sub OTUpdate(ByVal arr As Variant, ByVal therow As Long, ByVal thecol As Long)
    Dim updatecol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    updatecol = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("OT%").Range.Column

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If IsArray(arr) Then
            For i = 0 To (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr))
                .Cells(therow + i, updatecol).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, .Cells(therow + i, thecol).Value * .Range("slope").Value + .Range("intercept").Value) / .Cells(therow + i, thecol).Value
            Next i
        Else
            .Cells(therow, updatecol).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, .Cells(therow, thecol).Value * .Range("slope").Value + .Range("intercept").Value) / .Cells(therow, thecol).Value
        End If
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Module2:

```
Sub HoursUpdate(ByVal arr As Variant, ByVal therow As Long, ByVal thecol As Long)
    Dim updatecol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    updatecol = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Hours").Range.Column

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If IsArray(arr) Then
            For i = 0 To (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr))
                .Cells(therow + i, updatecol).Value = -.Range("intercept").Value / (.Range("slope").Value - .Cells(therow + i, thecol).Value)
            Next i
        Else
            .Cells(therow, updatecol).Value = -.Range("intercept").Value / (.Range("slope").Value - .Cells(therow, thecol).Value)
        End If
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

- How can I make this work for all rows in the table?

  - Done!
- Do I have to define the cells by Row # and Column Letter, or can I
  define by table name and row header?

  - Defined by table name and headers
- What if the end user pastes a value in both J and K by mistake?

  - This code will do nothing.  Values will be pasted without alteration.  The previous values are stored in an array, so the potential would be to add to this code to restore the previous values and generate an error message
- What if the end user pastes over multiple rows in J or K, updating
  multiple weeks simultaneously?

  - Works fine!
- Can I change the references to M and B to something named, perhaps in
  a hidden sheet?

  - Changed the cell names, now they can move around the sheet.  Some minor modifications would need to be made to move to another sheet.