# VBA Excel SelectionChange Reading Target Range into array and returning column count

Tags: excel, vba

When a new selection of cells is made, I want to convert the range into an array for later use, and determine the number of columns selected.  This is the code I have, but I get a type mismatch error.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim colcount As Long
    arr = Target
    colcount = UBound(arr, 2)
    Debug.Print colcount
End Sub
```

Comment: target.columns.count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `Range.Value` returning only a single value when the range only has a single cell.

If `Target` is a single cell, then `Target` will return a single value instead of an array. `arr` will be a single value and `UBound(arr, 2)` will error because `arr` is not an array.

You can use `IsArray` to check if `arr` is an array or not before attempting `UBound`. Also, if you intend to save these values for future use, you should define them as [Module-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level) variables.

```vb
Dim arr As Variant
Dim colcount As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    arr = Target
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        colcount = UBound(arr, 2)
    Else
        colcount = 1
    End If
    Debug.Print colcount
End Sub
```

To fill `colcount`, other than `UBound`, you could also just do `colcount = Target.Columns.Count` which would also avoid needing to check `IsArray`.

Comment: Probably worth adding a check for `Target.Areas.Count` in case of a discontinuous range being selected?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I left a few things out, to not over-complicate the example solution. Other than `Areas`, I would also check `Target.CountLarge < 1000000` before doing `arr = Target` because the user might have selected the entire sheet, which would fill the array with millions of values and likely cause an error.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you.  For discontinuous ranges, how can they best be handled?  I've been working on a larger project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71012510/worksheet-change-on-data-range-excel-table/71040198#71040198

Comment: `For Each Area in Target.Areas: colcount = colcount + Area.Columns.Count`. If you want to join the values from each area into the same array... that is too much code to fit in a comment. If you can't find any solutions online and can't figure it out on your own, make a new post on this site.